# How to securely implement cross-platform in-app purchase?

Tags: android, ios, security, encryption, in-app-purchase

I have a cross platform app for Android, iOS, and web, and am looking for the best way (in terms of simplicity and security) to implement in-app purchase that persists across platforms.

Since it's against their policy to ask users to pay through mediums other than platform specific in-app purchase, I have to use that for each mobile platform. But I want the purchase history to be persistent reguardless of what client used, and identified by a Facebook ID (that the user logs in the app with).

The obvious solution I can come up with is everytime a purchase is made for a Facebook ID, I also record it on my own server. Everytime the user requests a premium feature, I check my own server to see if the Facebook ID has paid. The problem with this is I'm not experienced with sending this kind of information securely over the internet, and somebody can easily send a fake message to my server forging a purchase.

What should I look into for sending things securely over the internet? For example, if I encrypt the purchase information using some key, how likely is it that somebody can figure out the key, either by sniffing the connection of inspecting the binary?

If this solution is wrong in the first place, what is a better one?

Comment: To secure the transmission all that is needed it https and certificate pinning. The real problem is authentication. How will you know when a Facebook ID made a valid purchase?

Comment: @zaph I use facebook id as the only means for the user to log in. This is essentially an app on top of facebook. Is this enough for that?